# Approximating derivatves and second derivatives of numerical functions in Common Lisp - not working as expected

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp, precision, numerical-analysis

I tried a very naive approach to aproximate the first derivative of a function in Lisp, and came up with something like this:

```
(defparameter *delta-x* 0.00001)

(defun diff (f x)
  (/ (- (funcall f (+ x *delta-x*)) (funcall f x))
     *delta-x*))
```

So that, for example

```
(diff #'(lambda (x) (* x x x)) 2)
; 12.016296
```

which is not bad (12 being the actual result). So I thought... why not? and tried to extend this to the second derivative approximation, using

```
(defun diff2 (f x)
  (diff #'(lambda (z) (diff f z)) x))
```

Realizing it may be a numerically inferior algorithm, I still expected some kind of results but I get 0.0 as the answer for everything I try, so my guess is the Lisp I wrote is not what I think it is...

```
(diff2 #'(lambda (x) (* x x x)) 2)
; 0.0
```

Any hints greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

LOL.  good news bad news....
The good news is that the lisp I wrote is doing what I thought I told it to do.
The bad news is I'm an idiot.

```
(defparameter *delta-x* 1/10000)
```

makes it work as expected.  Floating point arithmetic 101.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's ok, but you're at the limit of granularity of single floats.  You can see that with `trace`.

Try it with double floats or ratios.